# There are no changes reflected on deploying the theme in liferay 6.1.1

Tags: java, velocity, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am a newbie to liferay CMS. I am developing a theme in liferay 6.1.1. my problem is when i am making any changes to the theme it doesnt get reflected after deploying it.
Please check if i am in the right flow:

1. Firstly new --> liferay project --> selected theme
2. Deployed nthe theme which created the -diffs folder and the remaining all
   folders in the docroot folder inside the theme.
3. Copied the portlet_normal.vm from the template folder from my theme and made
   changes.
4. Pasted portlet_normal.vm  in my theme inside the docroot(folder) --> _diffs(folder) --> templates(folder).
5. Redeployed the theme but there were no changes reflected.

My portlet_normal.vm  file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

#parse ($init)

<html class="#language("lang.dir")" dir="#language("lang.dir")" lang="$w3c_language_id">

<head>
    <title>$the_title - $company_name</title>

    $theme.include($top_head_include)
</head>

<body class="$css_class">

$theme.include($body_top_include)

#if ($is_signed_in)
    #dockbar()
#end

<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#main-content" id="skip-to-content">#language("skip-to-content")</a>

    <header id="banner" role="banner">
        <div id="heading">
            <h1 class="site-title">
                <a class="$logo_css_class" href="$site_default_url" title="#language("go-to") $site_name">
                    <img alt="$logo_description" height="$site_logo_height" src="$site_logo" width="$site_logo_width" />
                </a>

                #if ($show_site_name)
                    <span class="site-name" title="#language("go-to") $site_name">
                        $site_name
                    </span>
                #end
            </h1>

            <h2 class="page-title">
                <span>$the_title</span>
            </h2>
        </div>

        #if (!$is_signed_in)
            <a href="$sign_in_url" id="sign-in" rel="nofollow">$sign_in_text</a>
        #end

        #if ($has_navigation || $is_signed_in)
            #parse ("$full_templates_path/navigation.vm")
        #end
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        **/*<nav class="site-breadcrumbs" id="breadcrumbs">
            <h1>
                <span>#language("breadcrumbs")</span>
            </h1>
            #breadcrumbs()
        </nav>*/**


        #if ($selectable)
            $theme.include($content_include)
        #else
            $portletDisplay.recycle()

            $portletDisplay.setTitle($the_title)

            $theme.wrapPortlet("portlet.vm", $content_include)
        #end
    </div>

    <footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <p class="powered-by">
            #language("powered-by") <a href="http://www.liferay.com" rel="external">Liferay</a>
        </p>
    </footer>
</div>

$theme.include($body_bottom_include)

</body>

$theme.include($bottom_include)

</html>
```

Actually i want to hide the breadcrumbs getting displayed in the home page. so i have commented that particular portion in portlet_normal.vm 
Any help regarding this will be appreciated , i am completely stuck in this.

Answer (score 2):

You have two possibilities:
If you are developping, you can set the portal in dev mode adding 
`include-and-override=portal-developer.properties` 
 into your portal-ext.properties which should be under the portal root.
If you are in production this option should be disabled and you should check the following

Try to open the XML file build-common-theme.xml under the themes folder in your SDK and remove all the `preservelastmodified="true"` (or set them to false).

preservelastmodified, when true will not update the files timestamp in your theme project. Therefore, your application server will not detect the changes and redeploy the theme.

Answer (score 0):

From step 1 it seems that you are using Eclipse to create Liferay theme project. Whenevr you create the project you will get

[image]

Now all you need to do is, change the files within the _diffs directory and build the theme with ant file build.xml, rest will be taken care by the build file. I am not sure why steps 3 and 4 required.

If the problem still exists, couple of points to look at are :

> velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=false

set this property in your portal-ext.properties and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks sharana for your help.
Actually when i created the new theme the _diffs folder was blank so i had to mandatory make all the inner folders and had copied the files which need to be overwritten, so i had to follow the step 3 and 4.
And as per your saying i made the changes in the portal_normal.vm file and build the theme with ant file build.xml but still nothing gets reflected in front.

Comment: Also i have added the velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=false in the properties file as told by you.
But don't know wats going wrong i dun see anything getting reflected in the front.
I have selected Classic theme in the look and feel for this theme, does this make any difference to my problem???
I am completely stuck in this problem. :(

Comment: Okay then, when you have copied what are all the files that you have changed? Only portal_normal.vm? when you are copying the folders from the classic theme, make sure you have not copied WEB-INF folder to _diffs directory. once you have built and deploy the folder to the server, you need to click on Manage and go to Look and feel change the theme to the newly created theme by you. let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have changed the portal_normal.vm and custom.css. Ya i havent copied WEB-INF folder. When i selected my theme from Look and feel there is no css getting reflected.

Comment: Also i have prepared the custom layout for my theme, the layout is working properly but how can i add a webcontent in a particular portion of layout. Actually i am not able to drag and drop the content in particular portion of layout. when i am adding any of the web content in the theme it is added serially one after the other but i want to reorder it. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: You can follow this link to create layouts http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Template . 

<td class="lfr-column twenty" id="column-1" valign="top">
   $processor.processColumn("column-1")
  </td>

$processor.processColumn("column-1") - is the key here to add portlets

Comment: Thanx for your support.. I have one more problem: when i am selecting my new theme the css doesnt gets reflected in front...

Comment: You may need to clear the browser cache and set 

theme.css.fast.load=false in portal-ext.properties

and restart the server

Comment: I did clear the cache and added the line pointed by you. But i found the problem is initially when i am starting eclipse the css loads correctly but after changing the portlet_normal.vm and deploying the theme via ant the css doesnt show up properly. And indeed the custom.css in _diffs/css folder as well as in /docroot/css both css gets changed. what may be the problem for this??